# Pycharm - unable to use fixutures or other resources from parent directories when running pytest

Tags: python, testing, path, pycharm, pytest

```
Pycharm version: 2022.2.3 (Professional Edition)
Framework: FastAPI
Tests: pytest 6.1.0
OS: macOS Monterey 12.4
```

There are a few posts about this with a few suggested solutions but from what I see it mainly comes down to improper configuration. This could be the case here as well but none of the previous solutions look to have worked.

Issue: I have a FastAPI project with tests that I can run from the terminal:

```
poetry run dotenv run poetry run pytest tests -k name_of_some_test_method -v -s
```

The test runs just fine without issues.

However when the same test is run from Pycharm, it still runs the test but it is unable to find resource files or fixtures from the parent directories.

It results in an error that a FileNotFound or it cannot locate the fixture.

Example - directory structure:

```
My_Project
  - App_code - sources root
     - admin
     - api 
     - auth
     - ....
  - tests
     - fixtures 
         - some_files
             - JSON files
             - datafile.json
         - some_fixtures.py
         - ...
     - unit
         - services
            - test_service.py
```

When an individual test is run from `test_service.py` that depends on the JSON files it is unable to locate them.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tests/fixtures/some_files/datafile.json'
```

The same will happen is the tests depends on a fixture with a different error message stating that the fixture was not found.

Some additional info:
[image: Setting pytest]

Could I ask anyone to shed some light on the matter? Your help would be much appreciated.
Thank you all for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get this file in the code?
Looks like you are doing something like: `my_json = 'tests/fixtures/some_files/datafile.json'`.
My suggestion is that when you run it with poetry, it "knows" where the project root is and finds the file without problems. But when you run it using Pycharm it tries to find 'tests' folder in the current directory where the file with the code being run is situated.
So, to be able to run it from pycharm, the path should be absolute or relative to the position of the file. The second option (relative) will make it possible to run both with pycharm and with poetry.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I really appreciate your time. I know that if use absolute paths it will work in pycharm but there should be no need to do this, there has to be a better way of doing this via pycharm. In VSCode it works without issues both via terminal and IDE.